# Minha saída dbms não é exibida

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, oracle10g, sqldeveloper

Eu estou testando uma saída simples do `DBMS` no SQLDeveloper. Criei a conexão, executei o `set serveroutput on` para habilitar as saídas `DBMS`, mas quando eu rodo meu bloco de código anônimo, na `Saída do Script` ele apresenta a mensagem

> Procedimento PL/SQL concluído com sucesso.

Mas na janela `Saída Dbms`, mesmo com minha conexão já adicionada, nada é exibido.
Este é o código que estou tentando executar:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(2000);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Curso Oracle PL/SQL');
END;
```

[image: Nessa imagem, é possível ver o código que tento executar e qual é o comportamento da IDE.]

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro execute somente essa linha:

```
set serveroutput on
```

Depois apague-a e programe normalmente.

Comment: Tem de clicar no (+) ...